# How can I add Volume/Series/Doi/ for Books

Tags: biblatex, biber

How can I add the Series for books as:

```
@book{blaa,
    Author = {First Last},
    Publisher = {GAGA Publishing},
    Address = {New York, NY, USA},
    Series = {Lecture Notes in Something Cool},
    Title = {Something Good},
    Volume = {75},
    Doi = {hahahaha/haha},
    Year = {2015}}
```

I use the following

```
 \usepackage[
  backend=bibtex,
        citestyle = alphabetic, 
        bibstyle = ieee-alphabetic,  
        sortlocale=en_US,
        sorting=nyt,
        backref=true
        hyperref=auto,
        firstinits=true,
        style=numeric,%style=alphabetic,
        defernumbers=true,
        isbn=false,
        eid=true,
        doi=true,
        series=true,
        bibencoding = utf8
]{biblatex}
```

But that does not print the DOI and Series only the Volume...?

**Update: it works and I used now these settings**

```
\usepackage[
        backend=biber,
        %citestyle = alphabetic, 
        %bibstyle = ieee-alphabetic,  
        sortlocale=en_US,
        sorting=nyt,
        backref=true,
        hyperref=true,
        firstinits=true,
        style=numeric,%style=alphabetic,
        defernumbers=true,
        isbn=false,
        %eid=true,
        doi=true,
        %series=true,
        eprint=false,
        bibencoding = utf8
]{biblatex}
```

Comment: books don't usually have a doi? regardless, yo'll need to supply `doi ={...}`  in your bibsource entry

Comment: ahh some stupid mistakes in bibtex, brackets forgotten

Comment: I just tested your `.bib` entry and got to see the volume as well as the series and DOI. So if you don't get to see it, something else is going on. Please note that `biblatex` does not know an option `eid` or `series` (this causes an error), you can only toggle on or off certain fields (including `isbn`, `url`, `doi`). Please note further that BibTeX cannot really deal with UTF-8 encoding, so `backend=bibtex,bibencoding = utf8` is not fully compatible. You also load several bibliography styles `citestyle = alphabetic, bibstyle = ieee-alphabetic, ` is later overwritten by `style=numeric`.

Comment: Could you solve this problem? I noticed that in your new question you use Biber and have addressed the problems I mentioned above.

Comment: I solved the problem, I use now the update posted.

Comment: If you could solve your problem, it would be nice if you posted the solution to a separate answer and accept it, so we know that the question is solved.

Comment: Sorry to bother you again, but is there a chance of you adding an extra answer, so this question can be marked as solved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using the following settings, the DOI  should be printed

```
\usepackage[
        backend=biber,
        %citestyle = alphabetic, 
        %bibstyle = ieee-alphabetic,  
        sortlocale=en_US,
        sorting=nyt,
        backref=true,
        hyperref=true,
        firstinits=true,
        style=numeric,%style=alphabetic,
        defernumbers=true,
        isbn=false,
        %eid=true,
        doi=true,
        %series=true,
        eprint=false,
        bibencoding = utf8
]{biblatex}
```